# Kick should be a synonym of kicking

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

This is an easy one. Please vote for [synonym](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: I think that was a fairly simple and easy one to decide on.